# How do I change the background color of my VAR impulse response table in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following are my codes, it is producing the standard graphic, but what I am after is to change the table colour of the white background. I don't know exactly how to embed ggplot2 into my existing code.

```r
# impulse response

GerIRF <- irf(VAR_aic, n.ahead = 20, ortho = TRUE)
GerIRF <- irf(VAR_aic, n.ahead = 20, ortho = TRUE)
 
plot(GerIRF$irf$FTSE100[, 1], xlab = "Periods after shock", ylab = "Response of FTSE100 to FTSE100 ", xaxt = "n", ylim = c(-00.10, 00.20), type = 'l')
axis(1, at = 2:30, labels = 1:29)
lines(GerIRF$Lower$FTSE100[, 1], col = "blue") 
lines(GerIRF$Upper$FTSE100[, 1], col = "green")
```

Standard graphic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first organizing your data in a tidy format. Then, you're basically ready to explore the universe of ggplot2.

You can find basic introductions in ggplot2 for example in the [R4ds book](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/data-visualize) and in [ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis (3e)](https://ggplot2-book.org/).

Below, I show you a minimal reproducible example, focussed on your question. Please note that we would never be satisfied with such a plot, including that we would never use the colours as they are shown in the example.

This example is in the sense of maximum simplification and serves only to illustrate the principle. As far as I see, in your case, `xx` could be `periode`, `yy` could be `response`, and `grp` could be your grouping variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  xx = rep(1:20, each = 3),
  yy = rnorm(60, 0, 1),
  grp = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 20)
  )

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = xx, y = yy, color = grp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed") +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue", color = "lightblue"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90", color = "grey90")
  )
```